# I keep getting Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, exception, pip

I've been trying to install MusicBot for Discord and got the above error when I ran it.  I also get the same error while trying to install RedBot or doing `pip install unroll`.  I'm on a Windows 10 computer and have Python 3.7.0b4.  I've looked at other people's solutions but they either used sudo or just didn't work for me.  I've already tried `pip install --upgrade setuptools` as well as `pip install ez-setup` and neither of them have done anything.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please copy the complete error trace and add it to your question.

Comment: unroll version 0.1.0,  Last released on Apr 16, 2014. Are you sure it works with Python 3? Especially with 3.7 beta?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my main issue, the music bot.  It was probably because it only works with python 3.5.4, not 3.7 which is what I used to have.  However, `pip install unroll` still doesn't work and continues to give me the same error, even on another computer that's also running Ubuntu.  But I'm not too worried about that so I'm not looking to fix it.  Thanks for the help though.